Definite integral involving K Bessel function and a square root
I have recently been trying to evaluate some integrals involving the modified Bessel function $K_0(x)$. The specific integrals are
$$L(x,u) = \int_0^{1} K_0\left( 2x \sqrt{r(1-r)} \right) \exp(2ixur) dr $$
where $x>0$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}$. I have found some (likely) answers in some special cases, namely $u=0$ and $u=1$. By expanding as power series and monkeying around with the terms, it appears that
$$L(x,0) = \frac{ \mathrm{Ei}(x)\exp(-x) - \mathrm{Ei}(-x)\exp(x) }{2x}$$
and
$$L(x,1) = \exp(ix)\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x} - \mathrm{Ci}(x) \right),$$
where $\mathrm{Ei}$ is the exponential integral and $\mathrm{Ci}$ is the cosine integral. I say these are likely answers because they seem to work to arbitrary precision, but I haven't proved them rigorously.
It seems like it should be possible to get a closed form in terms of both $x$ and $u$, given the relationships that exist between exponential and trig integrals, but I haven't been able to figure it out.
Important note: for my purposes, it is sufficient to get an approximation to these integrals that converges faster than Mathematica's generic NIntegrate function. That said, a closed form would certainly be much more pleasing :)

One idea that seemed very nice for the $u=0$ case is to use Graf's formula, as in this answer. After some substitution, the integral looks like
$$L(x,0) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi} K_0 \left( x \sin(\theta) \right) \sin(\theta) d\theta$$
and, using Graf, we get
$$L(x,0) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-4m^2} K_m\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) I_m\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$$
but I can't see how to show this gives the exponential integral expression above. And in the case of $u\ne 0$ this substitution makes the exponential much worse to deal with.

Edit Mathematica recognises the trig version of the $u=0$ integral as an incarnation of the Meijer G-function:

This outperforms NIntegrate by a huge factor:

For whatever reason, Mathematica cannot identify the version with the square root. It also doesn't know what to do with the general integral, either written as above or in trig form:
$$ L(x,u) = \frac{\exp(i x u)}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} K_0\left( x \sin(\theta) \right) \sin(\theta)\cos(x u \cos(\theta)). $$

Edit 2 (2024-06-27)
Playing around with the power series for $L(x,u)$ in $x$ in Mathematica, it looks like
$$ L(x,u) = \exp(iux) \left(  -\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{1-u^2}x)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}x}(\gamma + \log(x)) + R(x,u) \right)  $$
where $\gamma = 0.577\ldots$ is the Euler gamma constant, and
$$ R(x,u) = 1 + \frac{1}{36}(11-8u^2)x^2 + \frac{1}{7200} (137-244u^2+92u^4)x^4 + \ldots $$
The next few terms of the power series for $R$ are
$$ \frac{1089-3057u^2+2742u^4-704u^6}{2116800}x^6 $$
$$ \frac{7129 - 27256u^2 + 38364u^4 - 23056u^6 + 4505 u^8}{914457600}x^8$$
$$ \frac{83711 - 404695 u^2 + 774740 u^4 - 728540 u^6 + 329620 u^8 - 52064 u^{10}}{1106493696000}x^{10} $$
I have not been able to identify the polynomials in $u$, beyond noting that their constant term of the $x^{2n}$ polynomial coefficient seems to be $H_{2n+1}/(2n+1)!$, with $H_n$ the $n$th harmonic number.

Edit 3 (2024-06-27)
The presence of $\sqrt{1-u^2}$ in the $\sinh$ got me thinking that maybe this leftover function $R$ is also going to have a $\sqrt{1-u^2}$ in the mix, which suggests that one should really think about $R$ as a function of $x$ and $v$, where $v = \sqrt{1-u^2}$, which is achieved by replacing $u$ with $\sqrt{1-v^2}$ (since $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ is its own inverse, at least for real values of $y$). Suddenly the polynomials become a lot nicer to look at! We get
$$\begin{align}
R(x,v) =&  1 + \left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{2v^2}{9} \right)x^2 + \left( -\frac{1}{480} + \frac{v^2}{120} + \frac{23v^4}{1800}\right)x^4 \\
& + \left( \frac{1}{30240} - \frac{v^2}{6720} + \frac{v^4}{3360} + \frac{11v^6}{33075} \right) x^6 \\
& + \left( -\frac{1}{2903040} + \frac{v^2}{544320} - \frac{v^4}{241920} + \frac{v^6}{181440} + \frac{536v^8}{114307200} \right) x^8 \\
& + \ldots \\ 
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n(v) x^{2n}.
\end{align}$$
It appears that the polynomials $p_n(v)$ satisfy
$$ \frac{d}{dv}(p_n) = \frac{v}{2n+1}p_{n-1} + \frac{v^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)^2(2n-1)!};  $$
if this is the case, then $R$ satisfies the partial differential equation
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial v}(xR(x,v)) = x^2 v R(x,v) + \frac{xv \cosh(xv)-\sinh(xv)}{xv^2}.$$
Unfortunately, Mathematica cannot solve this partial differential equation:

Interestingly, we already have a solution to this equation: writing $y(x,v) = \frac{\sinh(xv)}{xv}(\log(x)+\gamma)$, a quick check shows that
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial v}(xy) = x^2 v y + \frac{xv \cosh(xv)-\sinh(xv)}{xv^2}.$$
But this is not the general solution, and it has been a long time since I took PDEs so I am unsure how to proceed from here to a general solution.
All of this is non-rigorous, but seems to work. I have added the partial-differential-equations tag to this question.

Edit 4 (2024-06-28)
It appears that the following is true: if we write $M(x,v) = x\frac{L(x,\sqrt{1-v^2})}{\exp(i x \sqrt{1-v^2})}$, then
$$ \frac{\partial^2 M}{\partial x \partial v} = xvM. $$
This can also be written as a differential equation for $L$ but that one is messier; this one is very clean. This is not an equation Mathematica seems to be able to solve. It is probably severely lacking in boundary / initial conditions, since it is solved, for example, by $M(x,v) = \frac{1}{v}\exp(xv)$. But this is clearly not the general solution, as it fails to reproduce the expression for $L(x,0)$ at the top of the post (now known to be true thanks to Mathematica).
The function $f(x,v) = (\mathrm{Ei}(xv)\exp(-xv) - \mathrm{Ei}(-xv)\exp(xv))/(2v)$ (which is just a reasonable guess at something that might work) comes close to solving the equation: it satisfies
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial v} = xvf - \frac{1}{v}. $$

Edit (2024-07-04)
I believe I have found a closed form expression for this integral. It seems that
$$ \begin{align*} 
L(x,u) = & \frac{e^{ixu}}{4\sqrt{1-u^2} x} e^{-\sqrt{1-u^2}x} \left( \mathrm{Ei}\left( \left( -iu+\sqrt{1-u^2} \right)x \right) + \mathrm{Ei}\left( \left( iu+\sqrt{1-u^2} \right)x \right) \right)   \\
& -\frac{e^{ixu}}{4\sqrt{1-u^2} x} e^{\sqrt{1-u^2}x} \left( \mathrm{Ei}\left( \left( -iu-\sqrt{1-u^2} \right)x \right) + \mathrm{Ei}\left( \left( iu-\sqrt{1-u^2} \right)x \right) \right). 
\end{align*}
 $$
I arrived at this "solution" in the following way. The copy of $e^{ixu}$ seemed to show up whatever choice of $x$ and $u$ were made, so taking it out of the formula, it suffices to consider the integrals
$$ L_1(x,u) = e^{-ixu}L(x,u) = \int_0^{1} K_0\left( 2x \sqrt{r(1-r)} \right) \exp((2r-1)ixu) dr. $$
Experimentation led to the differential equation
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (u^2-1)y = -\frac{\cos(xu)}{x}, $$
which seems to be solved by $y = xL_1(x,u)$. Mathematica returns the solution of this equation as (essentially) the above expression, plus some leftover terms with constants, but it seems as though these constants are 0 in all cases.
This is all very handwavey, but seems to work:



I have not proved that this actually is the closed form, but this is good enough for my purposes for now. I will leave the question open because it is not technically resolved. I have also edited the tags to reflect that this is a question of complex analysis, not real analysis as I had previously tagged.
I would also like to note that the differential equation for $L_1$ is not as bad as I first thought. It satisfies this differential equation in $x$, but also apparently satisfies
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial u}(L_1(x,u)) + xuL_1(x,u) = 0. $$
This does not seem to be a phenomenon unique to this integral. Replacing the $K_0$ in the definition of $L_1$ with a $K_n$ or $I_n$, one seems to always get a solution to this equation.
(Really I mean I have tried it for a few random choices and it seems to always be true).

For $x>0$ one has $$\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^{\pi} K_0(x \sin(t)), \sin(t) , dt=\frac{\text{Shi}(x) \cosh (x)-\text{Chi}(x) \sinh (x)}{x}$$ which eliminates the MeijerG function.

How do you prove this? Does it follow immediately from the MeijerG expression above? It also looks a lot closer to the expression for $L(x,1)$. Maybe the general expression is made of terms like $\mathrm{Chi}(\exp(iu\pi/2)x)$?

Try evaluating "Assuming[x>0, FullSimplify[...]]" using Mathematica where "..." is your integral or the integral result.

Also, many times you can use "FunctionExpand[...]" where "..." is a MeijerG function to obtain an alternate representation. For example here you can also evaluate "Assuming[x>0, FunctionExpand[...]]" where "..." is the integral result. Without the assumption $x>0$ you get a rather long and complicated alternate representation.
